# Sequelize: 1:m mapping through junction table

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Is there a way to invert a 1:m mapping (`Group hasMany Users`) through a junction table?

```
Group.hasMany(Users, { through: 'junctionTable'}) 
User.hasOne(Group, {through: '????'})
```

The docs don't really say if `hasOne` supports `through`

Comment: With 1300 rep you should know to post more code, no?

Comment: `Group.hasMany(Users, {through: 'junctionTable'})`
`User.hasOne(Group, {through: '????'})`

Comment: Not really significantly different if you know sequelize.

Answer (score 0):

After trying it out, yes in fact passing `{through: 'junctionTable'}` to `hasOne` will work.

Although `hasMany` must be changed to `belongsToMany` to allow a junction table.